# How do I deduce from the C++ Standard that an array [] has higher precedence than a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, grammar, declaration

I know that a declaration like

```
int* a[5];
```

declares `a` as an array of 5 pointers to `int`. But how do I deduce this, just by using the C++ Standard?

Comment: a is basically a pointer to an array of 5 int pointers.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif, that isn't the question; also, `a` is an array in this context, not a pointer to one.

Answer (score 5):

Just see the grammar of C++.

```
ptr-declarator:
    noptr-declarator
    ptr-operator ptr-declarator
noptr-declarator:
    declarator-id attribute-specifier-seqopt
    noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
    noptr-declarator [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
    ( ptr-declarator )
```

and

```
ptr-operator:
    * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
    & attribute-specifier-seqopt
    && attribute-specifier-seqopt
    nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
```

Thus this declaration

```
int* a[5];
```

may be written like

```
int ( * ( ( a )[5] ) );
```

That is `( ( a )[5] )` is a *noptr-declarator*  and `( * ( ( a )[5] ) )` is *ptr-operator ptr-declarator*.

A declaration of a pointer to an array of 5 integers will look like

```
int ( *a )[5];
```

Comment: I cannot understand how a grammar production could determine a precedence of operators in C or C++.

Comment: @Ayrosa As it is seen from the grammar a declarator can consist of two parts ptr-operator ptr-declarator. So at first the ptr-declarator is built and then the ptr-operator is applied.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, I used the wrong terminology, but I think you understood what I meant.